# What is this icon that looks like a battery with recycle symbol inside it?

Tags: notification-icons

I see this battery with recycle symbol icon to the left of the alarm icon for about 3 days.

[image]

I'm afraid it's a malware app. I tried to find it but couldn't. Also, Bitdefender anti-virus says your phone is safe.

What is this icon? How can I find what the icons shown in notification bar are for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the Power saving mode **active** notification icon on Samsung devices. Find out more at [Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com/using-power-saving-mode-samsung-galaxy-s7?_ga=2.2090673.1204898751.1515136094-411715436.1511599319).

*Answer to **second** question*: Just swipe down from screen-top. You can see notifications, tap on it, it will open that application. This [link](http://gadgetguideonline.com/s8/meaning-of-galaxy-s8-status-icons-and-notification-icons-in-samsung-galaxy-s8-and-s8/) shows list of major  notification icons for Samsung devices.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Power saver icon. If you want to disable it, just go to settings and disable power saver.